# How to solve Unclosed character class error

Tags: java, regex, string, exception, error-handling

This is my code:

```
string.replaceAll("(?i)["+key+"]\\S*", "[blue]$0[blue]")
```

it throws Unclosed character class

Comment: Does `key` contain some square brackets? Remember that `[` and `]` have special meaning in regexes and need to be escaped if you want them to stand for actual left- and right- square brackets. [`Pattern.quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) may be helpful.

Comment: String[] key = {"as","if","when","and","then"};

Comment: You might want to do `String r = "(?i)["+key+"]\\S*";` and print out `r`.  That's almost certainly _not_ the regex you had in mind.  What are you trying to do?  Replace `[xxx]` (where `xxx` is any of those words) with `[blue]xxx[blue]`?

Comment: yeah so replace all the keys (as,if,when,and,then) with [blue]key[blue] in the string "If if we write a program and compile it, then we can run the program to get if output"

Comment: The regex you ultimately want is `(?i)\b(as|if|when|and|then)\b
`; no string expression involving `...+ key + ...` is going to produce that.

Comment: @KevinAnderson - `String.join` should do the trick if we can trust that the keys don't contain regex meta-characters.

Comment: So, use `string.replaceAll("(?i)(?:"+String.join("|", keys)+")\\S*", "[blue]$0[blue]")`. Add word boundary at the start, `\\b` (after `(?i)`) if the match should start with the values in `keys`.

Answer (score 0):

Use groups and do not forget to escape your alternatives:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
 
class app
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        List<String> key = Arrays.asList("as","if","when","and","then");
        List<String> alternatives = key.stream()
            .map(Pattern::quote)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        String string = "AS?! When then";
        System.out.println( string.replaceAll("(?i)(?:"+String.join("|", alternatives)+")\\S*", "[blue]$0[blue]") );
    }
}

[**Java code demo**][1]
```

Result: `[blue]AS?![blue] [blue]When[blue] [blue]then[blue]`